# com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: java, jaxb

I get the following error when I changed the Java version from 1.7 to 1.6

```
Error while loading configuration file: 
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 3 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
weka.core.Instances does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at weka.core.Instances
    at public java.util.ArrayList lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner.getDecomposedDatasets()
    at lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner
    at public lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration.getLearnerEnvironment()
    at lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration
lpcforsos.dataStructure.ExtInstances does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at lpcforsos.dataStructure.ExtInstances
    at public lpcforsos.dataStructure.ExtInstances lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner.getTrainingSet()
    at lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner
    at public lpcforsos.baseLearner.DecompositionBasedLearner lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration.getLearnerEnvironment()
    at lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration
lpcforsos.evaluation.Result does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at lpcforsos.evaluation.Result
    at protected lpcforsos.evaluation.Result lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.StructuredPredictor.results
    at lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.StructuredPredictor
    at lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.PairwiseCoupling
    at public lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.PairwiseCoupling lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration.getPairwiseCoupling()
    at lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration

at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:436)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:277)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1100)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:143)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:110)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:376)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration.loadConfig(Configuration.java:387)
at lpcforsos.evaluation.Evaluation.main(Evaluation.java:68)
```

My XML is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<decomposer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="topicRankingDecomposer">
</decomposer>   
<learnerEnvironment xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="wekaBaseLearner">
</learnerEnvironment>
<structuredPredictor xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="wuLingWeng2">
</structuredPredictor>
<essentials>
</essentials>
</configuration>
```

Among the above tags decomposer, learnerEnvironment and structuredPredictor are abstract class
and each of them have 3 or more concrete classes. 
When unmarshalling the xml the corresponding concrete class objects are assigned to the abstract class variable.

I have used no annotations, and it worked just perfect when I used Java 1.7. now when I try using JDK 1.6 I get the above error.

```
public class Configuration {

private Decomposer decomposer;
// Subtypes of Decomposer
private ReinforcementLearningDecomposer reinforcementLearningDecomposer;
private OneAgainstAllDecomposer oneAgainstAllDecomposer;
private TopicRankingDecomposer topicRankingDecomposer;
private PairwiseDecomposer pairwiseDecomposer;

private DecompositionBasedLearner learnerEnvironment;
// Subtypes of BaseLearner
private WekaBaseLearner wekaBaseLearner;
private SeCoBaseLearner seCoBaseLearner;
// Predictor Instance

private StructuredPredictor structuredPredictor;
// Subtypes of Predictor
private PairwiseCoupling pairwiseCoupling;
private WuLingWeng2 wuLingWeng2;
private Voting voting;
private WeightedVoting weightedVoting;

// Other essential fields
private Essentials essentials;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions that you are encountering sound like real issues that cause problems with JAXB.  Below is one of them, is the following true?

```
lpcforsos.evaluation.Result does not have a no-arg default constructor.
this problem is related to the following location:
    at lpcforsos.evaluation.Result
    at protected lpcforsos.evaluation.Result lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.StructuredPredictor.results
    at lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.StructuredPredictor
    at lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.PairwiseCoupling
    at public lpcforsos.structuredPrediction.PairwiseCoupling lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration.getPairwiseCoupling()
    at lpcforsos.configuration.Configuration
```

It may be possible that the JAXB impl you are using in JDK 1.7 lazily processes metadata while the JDK 1.6 impl does not.  Are you able to unmarshal an instance of `lpcforsos.evaluation.Result` in JDK 1.7 or do you get the exception at that time?

Comment: Actually the classes I use are part of the framework which does implement logic apart from marshalling/unmarshalling. And all three of the above fields are not retrieved from the xml (are protected members and have getters and setters). And result field is not unmarshalled from the xml at all(as in I don't want to do it).